# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject from PubNub message

Tags: c#, pubnub

When I send in this message to MakeAction manually it works and the message box pops up:

```
string json = @"{'action':'turncompleted', 'messageID':'123123123',  'playerID':'100000067174580', 'round':1, 'values':[{'longitude':21.09375, 'latitude':24.527134822598}, {'longitude':1.40625, 'latitude':23.885837699862}]}";

public void MakeAction(string message)
    {
        Poker_Server_v4_0.Action a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Poker_Server_v4_0.Action>(message);            
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(a.action + a.messageID); 
    }
```

But when I use the message from PubNub it doesn't work:

```
static void DisplaySubscribeReturnMessage(string result)
    {
        //Receives the message from Pubnub takes care of the Action.
        MessageToAction MTA = new MessageToAction();
        MTA.MakeAction(result);
    }
```

The message from PubNub differes a little bit from the one that I created manually:

```
[{\"action\":\"turncompleted\",\"messageID\":\"123123123\",\"playerID\":\"100000067174580\",\"round\":1,\"answers\":[{\"longitude\":21.09375,\"latitude\":24.527134822598},{\"longitude\":1.40625,\"latitude\":23.885837699862}]},\"13926740640746402\",\"chinese-jefecito\"]
```

I tried to remove the brackets and the slashes the text but then the slashes around the "values" values also got replaces.

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the action class as well:

```
class Action
{

    [JsonProperty("action")]
    public string action { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("messageID")]
    public string messageID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gameID")]
    public string gameID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("invitorFacebookID")]
    public string invitorFacebookID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gametype")]
    public string gametype { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("numberOfPlayers")]
    public string numberOfPlayers { get; set; }
    //public List<string> longitude { get; set; }
    //public List<string> latitude { get; set; }
    //public List<string> values { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("players")]
    public List<Players> players { get; set; }

    //Should be empty and removed!
    [JsonProperty("values")]
    public List<Value> values { get; set; }


    public Action() { }

}

class Players
{
    //Players
    [JsonProperty("playerID")]
    public string playerID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("facebookID")]
    public string facebookID { get; set; }
}

class Value
{
    //Answers
    [JsonProperty("longitude")]
    public string longitude  {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("latitude")]
    public string latitude { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Tomas

Answer (score 1):

Alright, rather than offering corrections I'll just give you the code I would use. Note the sample json you posted is not valid. I'm removing this part; \"13926740640746402\",\"chinese-jefecito\"]   and closing the array of `Action` objects there. You can't have keys on their own in json (both those are keys without values) and also they're in the array rather than within an object. Anyway, here is the json I'm using;

[{\"action\":\"turncompleted\",\"messageID\":\"123123123\",\"playerID\":\"100000067174580\",\"round\":1,\"answers\":[{\"longitude\":21.09375,\"latitude\":24.527134822598},{\"longitude\":1.40625,\"latitude\":23.885837699862}]}]

```
public class Action
{
     public string action { get; set; }
     public string messageID { get; set; }
     public string round { get; set; }
     public Answer[] answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
     public string longitude { get; set; }
     public string latitude { get; set; }
}




Action[] actions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Action[]>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I changed it to Poker_Server_v4_0.Action[] a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Poker_Server_v4_0.Action[]>(message); but it still doesn't work. I have a breakpoint on public Action() {} which get triggered when I uses Action[] instead of Action however then it just stops. It doesn't give me an error message or anything, it just stops.

Comment: @user2524586 alright, I noticed something else that was weird. I just updated with code written from scratch. I had to change you json snippet because it wasn't valid json.

Comment: I actually noticed that to. I will check in the PubNub C# samples to see if they have any recommended way to retrieve a message. Once again, many thanks.

Comment: You can also contact us directly at support@pubnub.com, and we can work with you through direct channels to get you back up and running.